# Add to Cart button not working for me, but working for other users

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, addtocart

I just upgraded Magento from 2.3.1 to 2.3.2.  Now I'm having a weird problem where when I click "Add to Cart" for a product, the "Add to Cart" button gets disabled for a second as it's processing, but then nothing gets added to my cart.  This problem appears to only be happening for Chrome; I tried Edge and Brave and both of them behaved correctly (possibly because I hadn't logged on to the site from Edge or Brave previously).  Additionally, other users don't seem to have the same problem.

I tried `bin/magento cache:flush`, as well as deleting Chrome's site cookies and doing a hard refresh in Chrome, but none of that fixed this behavior.

What could be causing this behavior?

Comment: I suppose that you're working with localhost domain?

Comment: can you check if there is anything in the console (any JS error)

Comment: It's not localhost.  There aren't any console errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working in Localhost then this problem might occur on Chrome.

This issue is resolved by changing localhost to 127.0.0.1
Just chang the value of table core_config_data.

set web/unsecure/base_url to http://127.0.0.1